# Inverse Covariance Matrix Transformation from CAPM

Tags: finance, finance-mathematics, capm, covariance-matrix

Beginning with the CAPM model we have (with a risk free rate of 0%):

$r_i=\beta_i (r_m)+\varepsilon_i$

with $\varepsilon_i$ the diversifiable risks per assets

The variance matrix:

$\Omega = \beta'\beta \sigma_m^2 + Diag(\sigma_e^2)$

With $\sigma_m$  a constant, $Diag(\sigma_e^2)$ an N $\times$ N matrix, $\beta$ an 1 $\times$ N matrix.

Inverting the matrix we get the following result:

$\Omega^{-1} = Diag(\frac{1}{\sigma_e^2})-\frac{(\frac{\beta}{\sigma_e^2})(\frac{\beta}{\sigma_e^2})'}{\frac{1}{\sigma_m^2}+(\frac{\beta}{\sigma_e^2})'\beta}$

I don't understand how by using the inverse matrix transformation we find this result.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the result of the Sherman-Morrison inversion for the sum of an invertible matrix and an outer product. You will find this (and many other helpful methods) in the [Matrix Cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf). Specifically, this is equation 160 on p 18:

$$
\left(\boldsymbol{A}+\boldsymbol{bc}^T\right)^{-1}=\boldsymbol{A}^{-1}-\frac{\boldsymbol{A}^{-1}\boldsymbol{bc}^T\boldsymbol{A}^{-1}}{1+\boldsymbol{c^TA}^{-1}b}
$$

HTH

Comment: I like that equation 160 is already on page 18 :) Bookmarked.

Comment: Thank you for your help !